# Join data from multiple columns and send email alert from google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following sheet with multiple columns and rows of data. I want to send email alerts with data from more than 1 column (column A and D) and I have currently been able to achieve this for data from 1 column(column A). How can we map multiple columns in google script and add the data to the email?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Excel file sample]

```
function sendEmails() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 300; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A1:P300
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 16);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var dayofemail = data[0][15];
  data.reduce((m, [qua_num,,,,,,,,daysPastCal,emailAddress]) => {
  if (daysPastCal > -14) m.set(emailAddress, m.has(emailAddress) ? [...m.get(emailAddress), qua_num] : [qua_num]);
  return m;
}, new Map())
.forEach((qua_num, emailAddress) => {
  var message = qua_num.join("\n") + '\nThe above equipment are approaching due date or out of cal.\nPlease check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration.';
var subject = 'AUTOMATED ALERT: CHECK EQUIPMENT CALIBRATION ';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject + dayofemail, message);
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following script?

#### From:

```
  data.reduce((m, [qua_num,,,,,,,,daysPastCal,emailAddress]) => {
  if (daysPastCal > -14) m.set(emailAddress, m.has(emailAddress) ? [...m.get(emailAddress), qua_num] : [qua_num]);
  return m;
}, new Map())
```

#### To:

```
data.reduce((m, [qua_num, , , serial, , , , , daysPastCal, emailAddress]) => {
  if (daysPastCal > -14) m.set(emailAddress, m.has(emailAddress) ? [...m.get(emailAddress), qua_num, serial] : [qua_num, serial]);
  return m;
}, new Map())
```

- By this  modification, the value of the column "D" is added. So, `qua_num` of `var message = qua_num.join("\n") + '\nThe above equipment are approaching due date or out of cal.\nPlease check with QA for replacement or sending the equipment out for re-calibration.'` has 2 values of the column "A" and "D".

Comment: @Goutham Thank you for replying. About `For some odd reason I am seeing this error: Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient (anonymous) @ calibration_script.gs:21 sendEmails @ calibration_script.gs:18 Nothing in the changes should cause this but do you have any idea why?`, in this case, I think that it is required to check your Spreadsheet. Because my proposed script doesn't change your email address in your script. I just added the values of column "D". I deeply apologize for this. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your new issue?

Comment: I was able to address the email issue. This works but the data from each column is put in a new line. I would like to see 1 line (in the email) for each row of data in the sheet. Thanks

Comment: In the case of `m.has(emailAddress)` being true why do you add `m.get(emailAddress)` ?  In this example can there be more than one of the same qua_nums?